# Sending Message from My application using Fragment

Tags: android

I am sending sms from my app in fragment,I have code it works properly in Activity but it does not working in fragment.

```
    //---when the SMS has been sent---

    `getActivity().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "SMS sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Generic failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Radio off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    },new IntentFilter(SENT));`

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---

    getActivity().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    ///sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
    SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> parts =sm.divideMessage("You are assigning  to new booth with booth Number"+boothNumber.getText().toString()+"having username"+contactNumber.getText().toString()+",password"+contactNumber.getText().toString()+"@123");
    int numParts = parts.size();

    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numParts; i++) {

        sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0));

        deliveryIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0));
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    1);
        }
    }else{         //already has permission granted
        //SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        if(contactNumber.getText().toString().length()!=0) {
            //CustomerList customerList=allCustomerList.get(i);
            //Log.e("cs",customerList.getMobileNumber().toString());
            sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(contactNumber.getText().toString(), null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents);

        }
        // smsManager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber,null,smsbody, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

> java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10248 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
>   at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(SmsManager.java:623)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager#sendMultipartTextMessage(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E,%2520java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E,%2520java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E)) the method you're using only required `SEND_SMS` permission. However, perhaps the way you're handling permissions is the cause.

Your requests are using your activity to send them. You need to send these from your `Fragment`. To do this, remove the `ActivityCompat` and replace with `FragmentCompat` (you also will need to swap out `getActivity()`).

After doing this, also make sure in your parent `Activity` that you are calling `super.onActivityResult` and `super.onRequestPermissionResult` otherwise your `Fragment` will not get them.

Now instead of handling the permission requests in the `Activity` you need to handle them in your `Fragment`